# Dax - trouble with writing a simple RANKX expression

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I should start by saying I'm using a Live Connection over a Tabular model, so creating calculated columns with 'edit queries' is not an option unfortunately. Here's what my data looks like, with expected results:

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNcqL.png)

In my table visual, I need to create a measure that will rank my CASE_IDs, from '1' to 'N', whenever a CASE_ID has more than 1 SUB_CASE_IDs.
My end goal: to have a distinct values of CASE_IDs. After the measure is created, the idea is to filter out all the rows that are different than 1.

Some key points if I may:

1. I don't really care for the order of the SUB_CASE_IDs, or which row gets the value of '1'.
2. I know that by removing the SUB_CASE_ID column I get the distinct values of the CASE_IDs, but the thing is, I need to include the SUB_CASE_ID column because it adds another granular level (more rows) that I need to display, which I then also filter using other DAX measures.
3. In SQL, the syntax would look like this: rank() over(partition by case_id order by sub_case_id)

Hope I'm clear enough.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have unique sub_case_id? or a case_id can have same multiple sub_case_id?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
Rank = CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS('Table1'),
            FILTER(
                ALL(Table1),
                'Table1'[case_id] = EARLIER('Table1'[case_id]) && 
                'Table1'[SomeOfYourValueColumn] > EARLIER('Table1'[SomeOfYourValueColumn])
                )
                )+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicate **sub_case_id** for a **case_id**, this following measure can give your expected output-

```
row_number = 

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[case_id]
        ),
        your_table_name[sub_case_id] <= MIN(your_table_name[sub_case_id])
    )
)
```

**Now**, if you need to keep selected filters, the **Measure** will be bit different as below-

```
row_number = 

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[sub_case_id] <= MIN(your_table_name[sub_case_id])
        && your_table_name[case_id] = MIN(your_table_name[case_id])
    )
)
```

Here is the sample output-

[image]

Comment: Your solution works (!) when I try it in a brand new pbi file with this exact sample data, but unfortunately not in my original report. I'm really confused.. maybe it has to do with my table visual containing other columns from another table (related to my original table)?

Comment: cross check data type between two report. And hopefully you are trying with Measure.

Comment: Do you mean the data type that connects the 2 tables in the tabular model? because it's an integer key. Also, in both of the reports I'm working with integers. What am I missing here..?

Comment: which 2 tables you are talking about? In sample data, you shown only 1 table.

Comment: My bad nevermind, I think I've found the problem - when I use your measure on a small data size (only few case_ids) it works perfectly. But when I remove the filters pbi just chokes, and keeps showing this buffering icon.

Comment: Is there to many data in tables? Other wise this should work normally.

Comment: Less than 50k rows. Pbi now throws 'out of memory' error.

Comment: That case issue is not belongs to data as its a simple measure and amount of data is also small. Not sure where is issue belongs :(

Comment: Ok, one more question please: I see that this running number runs through all the rows in table, even if I filter CASE_IDs for the year 2020 - it still ranks rows from other years. Is it possible to write a measure that ONLY ranks the current rows in the table visual?

Comment: This will go through all records as per nature of measure. Not possible to calculate the row number for a specific row. Please explain if I get you wrong.

Comment: I want to create a dynamic running number only for the current rows displayed in my table visual. So if I filter the visual by 'Year: 2020' it will only rank the case_ids for this year.

Comment: Hi @Gilladriel, Can you please check my updated answer? I have added a new Measure code there.

Comment: Ok I tried the new syntax and it seems like the measure doesn't work when columns from another table are included in the visual. Any idea why?

Comment: Show your data from different table and relation between tables.

Comment: Oh God.. I just realized my reply didn't register here...
Anyway, I'm still struggling, the relations between the tables is very simple, like so:

https://i.imgur.com/JqPpFKv.png


Hope this clarifies enough.

Comment: Where is the YEAR column you are slicing with?

Comment: It's a really simple Date dimension connected to the Cases table, based on a Case_Date field.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample report file with some sample data? I can check in details then. You can share One or Google Drive link after keeping the file there.

Comment: I wish I could, I'm working in a very sensitive environment that doesn't allow data exporting of any sort. If you had a sample report what would you look for?

Comment: you can create dummy data with the issue we are talking on.

Comment: Even if I generate a really small sample report file? say 20 rows? because according to my testing it would work just fine.

Comment: Thats sad, do not know how I can help you now :(

Comment: Ok I just noticed something weird - the data in the table visual is pretty small, about 500 rows, BUT, the total value of the visual shows there are 32M (!!) rows, which does not make any sense whatsoever. Do you have any idea what's happening? By the way I appreciate you sticking up here with me so much!

Comment: Check relations between tables from the Model view. May be some un wanted relations are there.

Comment: Can't find anything suspicious but in the Tabular model most of the filter directions are to both tables, could this be a lead to something?

Comment: Both direction relation should not increase number of rows.

Comment: Then I can't the cause of this. I even deployed a copied test version of my cube, deleted most of the relationships just to see if it solves anything, with no success. Could it be a PBI bug?

Comment: possibility of being a BUG, is almost zero. Issues must be there in relations or in other setup. Can you query directly to the cube? This way you can check actual rows in the Cube.

Comment: I did query the cube, the rows are fine, I get the small number of records I'm expecting to get, its definitely a PBI thing, not sure wheres the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Add tables one by one if possible from the cube with relation and check in which steps the counting are increasing.